# Feature Extraction : SPTS and CAPP

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am trying to do facial expression recognition.I want to use Cohn Kanade dataset [(The Extended Cohn-Kanade Dataset (CK+): A complete dataset for action unit and emotion-specified expression)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Pi4-etrxwseWdWMGU4ZTROV1E/edit?usp=sharing). In paper SPTS and CAPP are listed under section FEATURE EXTRACTION. But I can't find any other information on SPTS and CAPP.

1. What are Full forms of SPTS and CAPP?
2. From where I can start reading?

Answer (score 2):

The paper is indeed not very good on providing the relevant  information in an easily accessible way.

SPTS: "similarity normalized shape features"

CAPP: "Canonical normalized appearance"

CAPP: They cite 3: ( A. Ashraf, S. Lucey, J. Cohn, T. Chen, Z. Ambadar, K. Prkachin,
P. . Solomon, and B.-J. Theobald. The painful face: pain expression
recognition using active appearance models. In Proceedings of the
9th international conference on Multimodal interfaces, pages 9–14,
Nagoya, Aichi, Japan, 2007. ACM. 5)